# Pass a 2D char array to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginning programmer who is confused with passing a two dimensional array to a function. I think it may just be a simple syntax problem. I've looked for an answer, but nothing I've found seems to help, or is too far above my level for me to understand.

I identify the array and the function in the main function as, and after initializing it, attempt to call it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int const ROWS = 8;
int const COLS = 8;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char board[ROWS][COLS];

bool canReach(char board[][], int i, int j);

//initialize array

//values of i and j given in a for loop

canReach(board, i, j);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

While writing the function outside the main function, I defined it exactly the same as I did in the main function.

```
bool canReach(char board[][], int i, int j){
//Functions purpose
}
```

When I attempt to build the program, I'm given this error twice and the program does not build:

```
error: array has incomplete element type 'char[][]'
bool canReach(char board[][], int i, int j)
                        ^
```

Please note that I'm trying to pass the entire array to the function, and not just a single value. What can I do to fix this problem? I would appreciate it if it didn't have to use pointers, as I find them quite confusing. Also, I've tried to leave out things that I thought weren't important, but I may have missed something I needed, or kept in things I didn't. Thank you for your time in helping out this starting programmer!

Comment: In C constants are actually variables the programmer guarantees not to change. For such as your array-size, it is the better way to `#define` them as macros. Note this its different from C++.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: The error is saying with reference to 2nd `[]` an array of what (How big is thing thing). Therefore you MUST specify the size of the array, for at least the 1st `[]`.  Alternatively you could pass a pointer to 0,0 and the 2 sizes.

Comment: Array indexes should be type `size_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass arrays as function arguments with definition of their size.

```
bool canReach(char board[ROWS][COLS], int i, int j);
```

When the size is unknown, pointers are the way.

```
bool canReach(char* board, int i, int j);
```

You should know, that **arrays != pointers** but pointers can storage the address of an array.

Comment: From what I remember of C classes, pointers are one of the most important things to master...

Comment: @LaurentS.: Yes, if you do not fully understand about pointers in C, you should not even think about writing code intendend to be actually used.

Comment: This comment helped me understand pointers better, I think. If I was to use the pointer method, then within the function, would I call to a specific place in the array the same way as I would in the main function ie.
    `board[i][j];`

Comment: With the pointer you got the address of the first element in your array. Now you have to work one-dimensional, but know: all elements are in row. F.e. given array x[2][3] is in memory x[0][0], x[0][1], x[0][2], x[1][0], x[1][1], x[1][2].

Comment: @Youka did you mean in the second example: `bool canReach(char** board, int i, int j);` and `bool canReach(char* board[], int i, int j);`? With `char *board` you can't access a 2d array like this `board[0][0]`

Comment: @tttony No, there's a difference between a **pointer** to the start of a multi-dimensional **array** of _char_ and a **pointer** to the start of an **array** of **pointers** to the start of an **array** of _char_! Data in last one isn't aligned and needs more memory because of pointers overhead. And `char* board` definitely works for `board[0][0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool canReach( int n, int m, char board[][m] )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++ )
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    return printf( "Hello SaarthakSaxena" );
}    

int main( void )
{
    const int ROWS = 8;
    const int COLS = 8;

    char board[ROWS][COLS];

    canReach( ROWS, COLS, board );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello SaarthakSaxena
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function inside another function (here: `main`) is not allowed in C. That is an extension of some compilers (e.g. gcc), but should not be used.

You have to specify the dimension of the array. C arrays do not have implicit size information as in HLL.

It also is not a good idea to use `const` *variables* for array dimensions in C. Instead

```
#define ROWS 8
#define COLS 8
```

Assuming `i` and `j` are the indexes of an element in the array, you can use the signature:

```
bool canReach(size_t rows, size_t cols, char board[rows][cols],
        size_t i, size_t j);
```

This allows to pass arrays of (run-time) variable size to the function. If the dimensions are guaranteed fixed at run-time:

```
bool canReach(char board[ROWS][COLS], size_t i, size_t j);
```

But only if using the macros above. It does not work with the `const` *variables*.

Both versions tell the compiler which dimension the array has, so it can calculate the address of each element. The first dimension might be omitted, but there is nothing gained and it would imhibit optional bounds checking (C11 option). Note the 1D-case `char ca[]` is just a special version of this general requirement you can always omit the left(/outer)most dimension.

Note I changed the types to the (unsigned) `size_t` as that is the appropriate type for array-indexing and will generate a conversion warning if properly enabled (strongly recommended). However, you can use `int`, but have to ensure no value becomes negative.

Hint: If you intend to store non-character integers in the array or do arithmetic on the elements, you should specify the signed-ness of the `char` types. `char` as such can be either unsigned or signed, depending on implementation. So use `unsigned char` or `signed char`, depending what you want.

Comment: `enum dim { ROWS=8, COLS=8 };` is even better: `gdb` understands enumerations and will print `ROWS` and `COLS` for variables declared with the type `enum dim`, and executing the line `enum dim x = 20;` and printing its value in gdb will print `(unknown: 20)`. As a debugging aid, the `(unknown: XXX)` output is wonderful for catching errors such as writing beyond the ends of arrays.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: `enum` constants are `int` by default, as much as the enum itself. I - in general - do not recommend to use `enum` for unrelated constants, as that implies a binding which does not exist naturally: Nothing wrong with macros in C; this is not C++. `size_t` is the most appropriate type for array indexing. Btw. gdb is also aware of such simple macros. Your approach would imply each dimenion variable can get either of `ROWS` or `COLS`, so you actually would have to create one enum with single constant per dimension. No, sorry, but I disagree.

Comment: "... and printing **its** value in gdb will print ..." You mean `x` by "its"? I think I do not get what you actually mean here. Please elaborate. As far as I see that, gdb will output `(unknown: ...)` for any value of the enum there is no constant defined. Sounds pretty useless, as you do not want to define a constant for _every_ valid index value.

Comment: Suppose you have a C file with `enum dim x = ROWS;` in it. `print x` will display "ROWS" rather than "8" (you can use `print /x ROWS` to display "0x8" instead, if you wish). If you assign a different value to `x` that is not specified in `enum dim`, such as 20, then `print x` will display `(unknown: 20)`. There is a slight flaw in my example since `ROWS` and `COLS` refer to the same value in this case, but in general, it works well when you have differing constants. That isn't the case with `#define ROWS 8` as `print /x ROWS` will print "No symbol "ROWS" in current context."

Comment: It will just print that for the exact match of the dimension For indexes 0..7 it will just print the (valid!) value as for an out-of-bounds value. OTOH, you have a signed integer for the dimension, not an unsigned, so gcc cannot even warn about conversion problems. Also, no one hinders be to use a different enum (e.g. confuse rows and cols) for the indexes. For printing macros: well, that works, I use it every day I debug my embedded project, e.g.: `print /x *SPI1` - `SPI1` being a macro. Perhaps you just don't add the correct ELF sections to your object?

Comment: `SPI1` is the macro? Printing its value works. Printing a variable that has its value results in whatever value it has being printed (e.g. `#define SPI1 8` followed by `int x = SPI1;` would display "0x8" after typing `print /x x`). Also, constants of this form tend to be more useful with an actual range of enumerated values. Perhaps it's time I revised my own practices. ;-)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: SPI is actually a pointer to a struct. I'm talking about bare-metal embedded systems. And, no, there is no gain in having them enum. Even for bitmasks for hardware registers, that is a problem, as C's enums do not allow to specify the type you need/want. I would agree, if C would allow something like `enum <tag> : uint8_t { ...` as in C++ (afaik). As specified now, enums are near to useless for many potential uses. For array-indexing, using an enum is definitively a bad idea. There is nothing gained to have just the length of the array see as symbolic constant, ...

Comment: ... and you hopefully agree defining a constant for every possible index is just nonsense. If you really want bounds-checking, use the corresponding C11 feature (if your compiler/environment supports it, of course) or assertions. Note: I'm talking about C; for C++ mileage may vary. However, enums are actually meant to represent a (small) set of specifiy values each with a specific meaning. Using an enumas an integer is actually abuse of the idea. Many stronger typed languages actually do not allow to use other values than specified by the constants.